# unable to see pcie nvme ssd content on windows when plugged in via usb

Tags: windows-10, usb, ssd, disk-management, m2-connector

I have a 256GB PCIe NVMe SSD whose contents I'm trying to read. I'm using a [Sabrent M.2 SSD to 2.5-Inch SATA III Aluminum Encloser Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N6PMZLW) and a [SYBA SI-ADA20155 1.58 ft. USB 3.0 Cable IO Crest USB 3.0 to SATA 6G Cable Adapter for 2.5" Hard Drives](https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16812186219?Item=N82E16812186219). Here's what Disk Management says:

[image]

Could the M.2 SSD to SATA3 adapter be bad? The USB to SATA3 works [when a 2.5" SSD is plugged into it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6hk7.png) - just not the M.2 SSD to SATA3 adapter.

Maybe I need special drivers to access M.2 SSDs via USB?

Comment: We need the specifications of the "SATA3 to USB3 adapter" if you want an answer.

Comment: @Ramhound - https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16812186219?Item=N82E16812186219 . I'll edit my original post.

Comment: The linked Amazon product page clearly states `Note: It doesn’t support M.2 NVMe PCIe SSDs`

Comment: @Robert - if you want 25 points post your comment as an answer. I'll upvote it and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Amazon product description](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N6PMZLW) clearly states that the Sabrent Harddisk Enclosure can't be used with MVMe SSDs:

> Note: It doesn’t support M.2 NVMe PCIe SSDs

Hence no matter what you do using this enclosure you will not be able to get access to the data on the M.2 NVMe PCIe SSD.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you are using the wrong hardware for the job. Save yourself this trouble by knowing what you're working with and reading the capabilities and specifications of the tools you're using to make sure you have the correct ones.

You will need to use an adapter that works with the specific type of drive you have. Recommending specific hardware is outside the scope of this site.